# How to get rid of messages like [Running] python -u "c:\Users\####\Downloads\Tutorial\HelloWorld\app.py" from output in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm running python on VS Code using extensions Python and Code runner.

I want to get rid of these messages from the output window when I run my code.

> [Running] python -u "c:\Users####\Downloads\Tutorial\HelloWorld\app.py"
>
> Hello World
>
> [Done] exited with code=0 in 0.106 seconds

Also I want the output window to show only the output of the code that I ran the last time like this

> Hello World

not the previous ones even if I run and compile the same code multiple times.

Comment: why would you remove some informations that can be usefull ?

Comment: @Cid It's distracting me. When I run code again the output goes to bottom. Sometimes I even have to scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

That output is from Code Runner. If you used the Python extension would drop the `[Done]` output but you would still have the command in the terminal for executing the file.

Otherwise I believe you can use "Start without Debugging" and look at the debugger output window.